# How to generate a custom token via HTTP REST APIs using an id_token

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to generate a custom token via an id_token.

Today, I have working code like this:

```js
/**
 * Generates a custom token we can use to sign in given an id_token
 * @param {string} id_token
 * @returns {string} custom token
 */
function get_custom_token(id_token: string): Promise<string> {
  return request.get({
    url: `https://us-central1-${firebase_config['projectId']}.cloudfunctions.net/create_custom_token?id_token=${id_token}`,
    json: true,
  });
}
```

I'd like to cut the latency down of this request and I am hoping there's a closer region than us-central-1 by chance.

Questions:

1. Where are the HTTP APIs for this documented? I've looked everywhere via Google but couldn't find anything.
2. Is there a closer region I can use?

Comment: Hi, I have found [this about Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-verify-custom-token), also [this about Generate an ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth) and [this about Verify ID Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients). About the locations, I will share this with you, about [Select locations for your project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations).

Comment: The locations must be the closer to your, as per my understanding, App Engine app. There is also a [CF locations doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is located here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations

Unfortunately, there isn't a us-west region yet.